# How to update Bigcommerce product image to image stored locally?

Tags: bigcommerce

Why I can't update image this way?

```
Bigcommerce::createProductImage($product_id, array('image_file'=>'/home/user/bigcommerce/api/picture.jpg'));
```

The follow code works:

```
Bigcommerce::createProductImage($product_id, array('image_file'=>'https://cdn6.bigcommerce.com/s-0cvdh/products/32/images/299/apitec71q__46081.1484240387.1280.1280__30161.1484331218.1280.1280.jpg'));
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://developer.bigcommerce.com/api/v2/#product-image-object-properties), it is not possible to upload an image locally. The docs say:

```
When specifying a product image, the image_file should be specified as either: 
a path to an image already uploaded via FTP to the import directory (with the path 
relative to the import directory); or a URL to an image accessible on the internet.
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't work because the BigCommerce servers have no idea where "/home/user/bigcommerce/api/picture.jpg" lives.  That's a file that exists on your local machine, and you're passing a string to BigCommerce telling it where to get the file.  It works in the second case because BigCommerce can access that URI.

In more general terms, you need to upload the image to a location that BigCommerce can access it, and then pass a URI that BigCommerce can use to retrieve the image.  It may seem a little cumbersome, but it relieves BigCommerce from having to stream large amounts of data through their API.